# Saving image files from Music21

Tags: python, music21, music-notation

I've downloaded a bunch of .krn files, and I'd like to convert them into images - either pngs or jpgs - using music21. I've tried this:

When I do this:

```
from music21 import *   
op = krnfile
s = converter.parse(op)
s.show()
```

I see a great image file in the Jupyter Notebook I'm using, but when I try to save that file programatically like this:

```
s.write(fp = 'outputfile.png', fmt = 'png')
```

It says:

```
Music21ObjectException: cannot support showing in this format yet: png
```

Which seems a little weird since it obviously manages to make an image for display in the notebook.

It looks like maybe I could use `LilypondConverter.createPNG(fileName=None)` from [this](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleLilyTranslate.html), but is installing Lilypond required? I already have MuseScore2 installed, which opens when I call `s.show()`.

Thanks a lot!
Alex

Comment: try `fmt = 'musicxml.png'` -- you need to convert it to musicxml and then have the helper-converter convert it from there to png, using musescore.  Or with lilypond (`fmt='lily.png'`)

Answer (score 1):

Install musescore on your computer, re-run `python -m music21.configure` to help it find it and then do:

```
from music21 import *   
op = 'krnfile.krn'
s = converter.parse(op)
fp = s.write('musicxml.png')
# or just s.show('musicxml.png') to test that it works.
```

If it's a multi-page file, fp will be the path to the first page.  It will end in -1 or -01 or -001 etc.  You can read through the directory to find other files with the same name until there are no more to get all the images.

Comment: This worked for me. the write method returned the file path for the png when using the musicxml.png argument

Answer (score 0):

If you use n.show('lily.png'), it should create a temporary png file somewhere. Try to use it and an image may open.

Sorry i don't know much yet, I hope it helps.

Comment: It does help, try to include some example of it working next time I am up voting it anyway welcome to SO

Comment: `n.show('lily.png')` throws the same error that Op gets.

Comment: In general, you'll get much better results with MuseScore and the musicxml.png format.  The main music21 dev team hasn't worked on the Lilypond code for over a decade (none of us are fluent in Scheme)